# mysql и одновременные обращения

Tags: mysql

при написании запросов к базе данных Mysql, возник вопрос.
Я получаю последнюю запись в бд, выбираю инкрементный ID(первичный ключ), потом увеличиваю на единицу для того, чтобы указать этот ID в запросе INSERT INTO .
Вопрос простой: Не возникнет ли проблем при одновременных запросах нескольких посетителей страницы(например 200 посетителей). Не будет ли такой ситуации, что пока извлекается последняя запись у одного посетителя, у другого произошел уже запрос INSERT INTO, у первого будет уже устаревший последний ID?
извиняюсь, за возможно, глупый вопрос. но буду рад пояснениям. Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем вы получаете будущий ID и пытаетесь его  использовать. Поля auto_increment для того и придуманы, что бы этого избежать. Вы просто не указывайте в запросе insert это поле и тогда БД сама назначит значение и гарантированно уникальное. Если вам этот ID нужен для использования еще где нибудь то _после_ вставки вы можете его получить с помощью функции last_insert_id()

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike, за ответ. да, точно, я забыл про last_insert_id(). Задача такая: формируется заказ товаров, у заказа есть подзаказы. При сохранении заказа в БД нужно сохранить и подзаказы, указав к какому № заказа они принадлежат. 1 таблица Заказы, 2- ая Подзаказы.

Comment: Ну тогда он (last_insert_id()) как раз для вашей задачи :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно вы думаете. Именно так оно и будет работать! 
Другими словами в mysql хранится информация про auto_increment - это id следующей (будущей) записи которая будет добавлена!

Если 200 человек одновременно получат это число, то любой кто сделает insert автоматически нарушит цепочку остальных 199 запросов.

Comment: Спасибо, @Deniss. А как вы думаете, как можно решить эту проблему? только транзакциями?

Comment: А какая вообще цель, или для чего это необходимо?

Comment: цель: генерировать № заказа так, чтобы при вставке в бд не было  проблем вышеописанных. Задача следующая: формируется заказ товаров, у заказа есть подзаказы. При сохранении заказа в БД нужно сохранить и подзаказы, указав к какому № заказа они принадлежат. 1 таблица Заказы, 2- ая Подзаказы.

Comment: Используйте в таком случае mysqli_insert_id() - он даст id который только что добавили в базу. Таким образом вы сможете связать две таблицы между собой.

Comment: Спасибо, @Deniss